# grafana behind a nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, grafana

I try to run grafana and nginx as reverse proxy in a kubernetes cluster and I already found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50410503/grafana-behind-nginx-reverse-proxy-returns-alert-title) but this seems not to work for me. At least I get the same {{alert.title}}-Message as Oles. That's why I would like ask again and maybe someone can give me a hint what I am doing wrong?

The configuration for the grafana deployment contains the following part:

```
env:
  - name: GF_SERVER_DOMAIN
    value: "k8s-4"
  - name: GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL
    value: "http://k8s-4/grafana"
```

and I don't modify the grafana.ini inside the container/pod.

Further I configure the nginx in the default.conf as following:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost k8s-4;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    location /grafana/ {
        proxy_pass http://k8s-4:30080/grafana;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host k8s-4;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server  k8s-4;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
  }
```

But as I say above this leads to the alert.title Error. But if I set the context to the root Element and configured the tools as follows:

**deployment:**

```
env:
  - name: GF_SERVER_DOMAIN
    value: "k8s-4"
  - name: GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL
    value: "http://k8s-4"
```

**nginx - default.conf**

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost k8s-4;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://k8s-4:30080/grafana;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host k8s-4;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server  k8s-4;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location /grafana/ {
    }
}
```

it works...
That's why I am quite sure this is a problem with the deployment of grafana but I don't see the error. Maybe someone here can give me a little hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first `server` setup is almost correct, you need to change the `proxy_pass` line to:

`proxy_pass http://k8s-4:30080/;`

Comment: I must be blind... thanks for the hint this is the solution for my problem :-)